# KOMA-Script: Indent Paragraph but not Headings

Tags: margins, koma-script

I want to increase the left margin of paragraphs, but keep headings as they are. It should look similar to the layout of the hitec class.

I am using the `scrartcl` class.
So far I tried

```
\setlength{\leftskip}{3cm}
```

The results looks well for text, but e.g. lists were not indented. What is the right (KOMA-Script) way to do that?

Comment: Set the right margin for everything and shift the *headings* around.

Comment: Shifting everything, also shifts headers and footers, which is not intended.

Comment: Are you intendig to shift every bit of text, or just some selected sections?

Comment: The whole text should be shifted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question. So I do not know which KOMA-Script class is used and if the document is onesided or twosided. So here is an example for twosided `scrbook` using `geometry` and `scrlayer-scrpage`. If you use the outdated package `scrpage2` or `fancyhdr` (not recommended for use with KOMA-Script) see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/302767/43317).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\LeftMargin{3cm}
\geometry{
  layoutsize={21cm-\LeftMargin,27.9cm},
  layoutoffset={\LeftMargin,0cm},
  reversemarginpar,
  inner=2cm,
  outer=4cm,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=4cm,
  heightrounded,
  %showframe% to show the pagelayout
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \hspace*{-\LeftMargin}%
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth+\LeftMargin}{\raggedchapter\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}%
}
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \hspace*{-\LeftMargin}%
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth+\LeftMargin}{\raggedsection\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[
  headwidth=\the\textwidth+\LeftMargin:-\LeftMargin:\LeftMargin% enlarge the headwidth
  ,headsepline,plainheadsepline% to make the header visible
  ,footwidth=head:-\LeftMargin:\LeftMargin% enlarge the footwidth
  ,footsepline,plainfootsepline% to make the footer visible
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using `scrartcl` remove the lines which redefines `\chapterlinesformat` and change the `geometry` settings because `scrartcl` is onesided.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/10/03]
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\LeftMargin{3cm}
\geometry{
  layoutsize={21cm-\LeftMargin,27.9cm},
  layoutoffset={\LeftMargin,0cm},
  reversemarginpar,
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=4cm,
  heightrounded,
  %showframe% to show the pagelayout
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \hspace*{-\LeftMargin}%
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth+\LeftMargin}{\raggedsection\@hangfrom{#3}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[
  headwidth=\the\textwidth+\LeftMargin:-\LeftMargin:\LeftMargin% enlarge the headwidth
  ,headsepline,plainheadsepline% to make the header visible
  ,footwidth=head:-\LeftMargin:\LeftMargin% enlarge the footwidth
  ,footsepline,plainfootsepline% to make the footer visible
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with the enumitem package.

```
\RequirePackage{calc}
\newlength{\textleftmargin}
\setlength{\textleftmargin}{3cm}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\leftskip}{\textleftmargin}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=\textleftmargin}
\setlist[enumerate]{leftmargin=\textleftmargin}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=\textleftmargin+1cm,labelindent=\textleftmargin}
```