# How to indent entire section heading and indent second line, if it comes, further

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I am formatting my CV in latex, and I currently have all my section headings indented by 2em. The first item is the date of the `\NewEntry` and after that I have `\hspace{1.5em}` inserted to separate the date from the position field. However, some of my position titles are longer than one line. As such, the second line conforms to the 2em indent that applies to the entire heading (meaning it is aligned with the date). But what I want the second line to do, should it come, is to conform to the beginning of the position title (i.e. `\hspace{1.5em}` after the date entry. So, essentially, I want an indent within an indent, or something of that nature.

Note: If I manually enter an `\hspace` into my position title where I want the second line text to indent, which is an annoying solution anyway, no change results.

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\reversemarginpar 

\newcommand{\MarginText}[1]{\marginpar{\raggedleft\itshape\small#1}} 

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} 
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} 

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{\noindent \hangindent=2em\hangafter=0 \parbox{\datebox}{\small \textit{#1}}\hspace{1.5em} #2 #3 
\vspace{0.5em}} 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{cv}

\NewEntry{2013}{Research Fellow, Ronald McDonald International Fellowship, Institute of Multidisciplinary Education} 

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Here is how this looks:

```
2013     Research Fellow, Ronald McDonald International
Fellowship, Institute of Multidisciplinary Education
```

Here is how I want it to look:

```
2013     Research Fellow, Ronald McDonald International
         Fellowship, Institute of Multidisciplinary Education
```

*Keep in mind that this entire section is already indented 2em. In addition, I want to indent Fellowship 1.5em (as shown in the immediately above example).

Comment: Well first of all could you bring us a whole MWE? The preamble is ok, but if you could and something inside the environment `document` would be better.

Second, I see you're trying to create your CV using the KOMA script bundle, it's fine, but there are [few templates in LaTeX](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae) for that stuff. You can download or try them online using the WriteLaTeX or ShareLaTeX services. 

Take a look, maybe you'll find them easier to use.

Comment: @Aradnix Actually you'll see that a large portion of the preamble is borrowed from the ClassicThesis-Styled CV template from the link you provided. Regardless, having indented the entire section in the preamble, and then (unsuccessfully) trying to further indent the second line of the section heading, should it come, remains my issue.

Comment: Well I see. Now I'm understanding the problem better, anyway, could you complete your MWE by adding something to the body (after `\begin{document}`)? 

No need to put personal information, only to have the MWE actually functional and ready for compile without errors. That way it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Aradnix I added an example of a section heading. In this example the section title goes to a second line somewhere around "Fellowship". I want that second line to be directly under "Research Fellow" and not as it currently is under "2013"

Comment: I revised your updates and your code, and I fear I don't understand well what you want to do. Why don't simple download the [Classicthesis-Styled CV](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv) and use it? 

In the other hand, perhaps [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25082/customizing-indentation-in-section-and-subsection-headings?rq=1) and [this other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30965/indent-an-entire-paragraph-section?rq=1) could be helpful.

Comment: @Aradnix: So are you interested in [this kind of output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TYtHd.png)?

Comment: Not me but perhaps it is what @JenniferBoylan is looking for.

Comment: @Werner: yup! Except the 2013 is also indented 2em. There is a 1.5em space separating the 2013 and Research Fellow.

Comment: @JenniferBoylan: Note that `\NewEntry` is defined to take 3 arguments yet you only supply it with 2. In this case there aren't any problems, but my answer adds a dummy `{ABC}` as the 3rd argument.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a start:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis} 
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} 

\newlength{\datebox}\settowidth{\datebox}{Spring 2011} 

\newcommand{\NewEntry}[3]{%
  \parshape 1 \dimexpr 3.5em+\datebox\relax \dimexpr\textwidth-3.5em-\datebox\relax%
  \noindent\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\dimexpr 1.5em+\datebox][l]{#1}}%
  #2 #3
}
\vspace{0.5em}} 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent \rule{2em}{1pt}

\begin{cv}
  \NewEntry{2013}{Research Fellow, Ronald McDonald International Fellowship, Institute of Multidisciplinary Education}{ABC}
\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

`\NewEntry` is set using `\parshape 1 <indent> <width>`, which changes the shape of the entire paragraph. Each line will be indented by `<indent>` and have a width that spans the remainder of the line. `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) would also have worked here.

The `\rule` is meant to highlight the fact that the date is indented by 2em.

Comment: that did the trick!